# Getting data from the database based on dropdown selection in Symfony forms

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I have two Entities, First one is the Company Entity and the other one is Events Events Entity.

```
ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Company", inversedBy="events"
```

On the events from I have created a drop-down doing something like following.

```
->add ( 'company' , EntityType::class , [
                'class' => Company::class ,
                'choice_label' => function ( Company $company ) {
                    return $company->getName ();
                }
```

is there any way I can obtain other values from the database for the selected company. In the database, there is a column called app_client_id which I want to get on dropdown selection so I can use that to call external API'S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, in the dropdown, you get the result of the __toSring() function in the entity. Consider setting there what you want to read when selecting.

Comment: app_client_id is in which entity ?

Comment: According to the explanation, it should be Company.